# How to convert std::set to std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have std::set and I need to convert it to std::array. Order of elements doesn't matter.

The opposite conversion seems to be simple, because I can just do:

```
std::array<T> array;
std::set<T> set(array.begin(), array.end());
```

But unfortunately std::array doesn't have constructor like this, so I'm unable to do:

```
std::set<T> set;
std::array<T> array(set.begin(), set.end());
```

What's the proper way of such conversion?

Comment: Are you sure you want `std::array` and not `std::vector`?

Comment: `std::array` needs to know its size at compile time, while `std::set` is dynamically sized. So this is not really possible unless you know the size is fixed.

Comment: There isn't `std::array<T>` there's only `std::array<T,N>`. The size must be known at compile time.

Comment: I was sure, that I needed an array, because I thought that vector has O(n) access complexity. I always treat it by mistake as Linked List. Thank you all.

Comment: Don't assume that a set is faster than a vector for looking up an element. It is for large sizes but not for smaller ones. For just traversing, vector is always faster.

Comment: @doug "For just traversing, vector is always faster." traversing a vector is just about as fast as it gets in terms of traversing a container, but that doesn't necessarily make if faster than something like set.

Comment: @George  While it is possible to design a set such that all the elements are stored contiguously hence would be as fast to traverse as a vector, it would do so at a materially increased cost to element lookup. That would be a poor set design as fast lookup is the principal reason for set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, `std::array` is not suitable for this as the size must be known at compile time.  `std::vector` is an appropriate substitute.

Here's one way to populate a `vector` from a `set`.  It should be straightforward to convert this to a template.  Note the use of `reserve` for efficiency:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::set <int> s = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector <int> v;
    v.reserve (s.size ());
    std::copy (s.begin (), s.end (), std::back_inserter (v));
    for (auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DfRoM8V4waur8hcu)

Comment: I would recommended you explain why `array` is not appropriate in this case.

Comment: @L.F. OK, done (I had not done so because it was already covered in the comments to the original question).

Comment: You can shorten it to a one-liner: `std::vector <int> v(s.begin(), s.end());`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I found a better way (than my original) using `std::copy`.  This, I imagine, is the most efficient way to do it if the set is large because you can call `reserve` before populating the array.

Comment: The one-liner should be even faster.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Why would that be?

Comment: @PaulSanders Nevermind, I profiled it and my suggestion turned out to be approximately two times slower. C++ is weird, I stand corrected.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's the call to `reserve` that speeds things up, I believe.  Without that, the vector has to be continually resized (exponentially, usually) as more elements are added.  The bigger the set, the more this costs you.

Comment: @PaulSanders I forgot for a second that you can't get `set` size from its `begin` and `end` iterators in O(1). You're probably correct, but I got some weird profiling results here: http://quick-bench.com/OuvJmIVWxFASUenLw0E4KS92WDQ

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Interesting.  I did two things: (1) commented out the calls to `reserve`, which to my surprise made no difference, and (2) added a benchmark calling `push_back` in a loop, which was as fast as calling `std::copy`.  Go figure.  I also tried it with clang, and got the same results.  I guess it just goes to show that one shouldn't make assumptions when performance matters.  Results with gcc [here](http://quick-bench.com/uI7xw6Qq457WCRugEUImoRrmDLY).